# Using two 30" LCD screens with a MacBook Pro

Tags: mac, macbook-pro

How can I use two 30" LCD screens with my 2011 MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the USB2VGA is that you won't be able to drive the full resolution of a 30 in, which is 2560x1600.

Technically, the 2011 MB Pro is capable to drive the 2 monitors, but since there is only one thunderbolt connector you can only connect one Mini Display Monitor. You can however connect two Apple Thunderbolt displays, since they connect to the MB Pro using Thunderbolt and not Display Port. Then you would have the use of the full resolution of both displays.

Sorry, but a 30 in monitor is the biggest one that can be connected to any computer, adding one is asking a lot from a connectors-limited portable...

Good luck!

Comment: Correct. Without daisy chaining Thunderbolt displays, and foregoing USB-related video output (not great), you're stuck at one.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your first LCD with the miniDisplayPort to VGA/DVI converter.  And connect your second LCD with a USB2VGA cable.

Comment: Incorrect. You will either need the ($100) **active** display-port -> **Dual-Link** DVI converter, or a monitor with a built-in display-Port, and a Mini-display-port to display-port cable. The standard mini-display-port to DVI dongle only supports 1920*1200, and all 30" monitors are much higher resolution.

Comment: @FakeName Also incorrect. The newer adapters are digital, and can convert backwards with a passive converter. You would need an active converter only if you were going from a DVI-enabled laptop to a Mini DisplayPort display. kukoo had it right.

Comment: @David Metcalfe - You are still incorrect. The critical thing here is that a 30" monitor needs **dual-link** DVI. See the apple support documents here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3571 http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3382. You **HAVE** to buy the $100 adapter to get a **dual-link** DVI output from a laptop with only a mini-display-port output.

Comment: @David Metcalfe - The **passive** mini-display-port to DVI adapter only supports **single-link** DVI. From http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3382 - `Apple Mini DisplayPort to DVI adapter - Displays that do not support Dual-link DVI resolutions (DVI displays with a resolution of 1920 x 1200 or lower)`.

Comment: I know what I'm talking about here. I recently went through the affair of trying to get my MacBook Pro to work with my 30" HP ZR30w at native resolution. The solution wound up being tracking own a mini-display-port to display-port cable, which was a pain in the ass.

Comment: @David Metcalfe - As an aside, DVI and DisplayPort are both purely digital interfaces, so the comment `The newer adapters are digital` is nonsensical, unless you are confusing DisplayPort with VGA.

Comment: As an aside, Apple stopped manufacturing laptops with *DVI outputs* in 2008. DisplayPort is **NOT** DVI. The displayport interface hardware can emulate a single-link DVI interface, to enable passive DP-DVI adapters to work, but displayport is a different protocol from DVI.